# Why is the first element returned taller than all other elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

This is my first time asking a question here, so go easy on me!

In my effort to learn React, I've created a simple search app that returns dummy data. Basically, you pick the department, and the results show a contact card for each user in that department. I've got it to the point in which the search categories are fetched and displayed correctly, and the contact cards are populated correctly. What has me currently stumped is why the first element always adds space (24.5px) at the bottom of the div underneath the image.

I would add an image here, but stackoverflow says I don't have "enough points" yet. Here is a link to the files: https://gist.github.com/EnArkhe/ec578017e42fd634184a9ad3fa23eb01

I expected the height of each contact card to be equal.

- The length of the content does not change, so it's not just making room for longer content.
- It's the same in different browsers.
- I've examined and compared the first contact card with the others in the browser dev tools, but I don't see any different CSS styles applied.
- Nevertheless, I suspect the problem has to do with either the semantic-ui CSS or SearchBar.module.css.

Comment: Am not familiar with semantic UI, but looks like each element should be wrapped in `Grid.Column`: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid/#content-rows

Comment: You're far more likely to get help if you make it easy to see the problem you've encountered. I'm personally not going to go to another site to read your code and then try to visualize how it would render, nor will i copy it down and run it.

Comment: Your solution worked, @cYrixmorten. I am so relieved. Thanks for helping out a newbie!

Comment: Thanks for your input, @ray. I wasn't sure what proper etiquette is for questions about React apps which contain various component files. I was worried about overloading my question with all the code. Currently, StackOverflow won't let me include any images, so that wasn't an option. Going forward, I suppose I'll just add the code in the description, even if it is spread across several files. If you have any other tips for asking questions more effectively, I'm eager to learn!

Comment: Great to hear that it worked :D you are welcome. There are tools like Stackblitz and JSFiddle where you can fairly easily create a small application to reproduce the problem and let others execute and play around with it.

Comment: Cool, I'll check those out. Thanks for the tip, @cYrixmorten!